# unable to place breakpoints in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, breakpoints, java-6

I am using eclipse europa (3.5) on windows vista home premium 64-bit using JDK 1.6.0_18 (32 BIT).

Normally, I am able to put breakpoints just fine; However, for a particular class which is NOT part of the project (this class is inside a .JAR file (.JAR file is part of the project) ), although I have attached a source directory to this .JAR file, I am unable to place a breakpoint in this class.

If I double-click on the breakpoint pane(left border), I notice that a class breakpoint is placed. I was wondering if there was NO debug info; However, found that this particular class was compiled using ant/javac task using debug="true" and debuglevel="lines,vars,source". I even ran jad on this class to confirm that it indeed contained the debug info.

So, why is eclipse preventing me from placing a breakpoint ?

EDIT : Just so everyone understands the context, this is a webapp running under tomcat 6.0. I am remote debugging the application from eclipse after having started tomcat outside. The application is working just fine. I am trying to understand the behavior of the above class which I'm unable to do since eclipse is not letting me set a BP.

P.S : I saw a few threads here talking about BPs not being hit but in my case, I am unable to place the BP!

P.P.S : I tried JDK 1.6.0_16 before trying out 1.6.0_18.

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Did you try to step into the class from a calling class? Did it show the attached source? Not a solution but may help.

Comment: josefx : This class was being called using Reflection which takes quite a few HOPs before the actual method gets hit, i did not step into the method.

Answer (score 4):

Try to take a look at your configuration Java->debug->Step filtering 
sometime its enabled and you cannot stop inside a filtered package

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like Eclipse cannot find the jar file on the classpath, although you did say that the jar file is part of the project. What happens if you run the application normally? Do you get a ClassDefNotFoundException or something similar?

If you check the tabs on the Run/Debug configuration you should be able to see what paths and jar files are on the classpath at runtime. You can also add jar files that are not needed to build the application but are needed to run it.

Comment: hi richj,
  thanks for your note. when i try to lookup the class using CTRL + SHIFT + T(open type), I am able to open that particular class and eclipse shows me the source that I attached to the .JAR.

  Although I am able to put BPs on classes that are part of the project, I am unable to put BPs on the above class.

Comment: That implies that the jar file is on the build classpath. The runtime classpath is not necessarily the same as the build classpath, but I admit this is a long shot as you usually need to actively change it to force the two classpaths to be different. If the application runs through the code when not using the debugger then the problem must be something different.

Comment: In this case I would be tempted to set up a small test project to try to work out what is going on. It only needs to contain the problem jar file and a small class containing one or more test methods.

Comment: hi richj,
  I also resolved along similar lines :-)
the application works just fine -- it's just that I need to understand exactly how this .JAR classes work.

thank you.

Comment: hi richj,

  I kinda resolved to such a solution.
As you mentioned, the application runs just fine with OR without the debugger. I just want to understand how the code works so I need to be able to set BPs on various classes methods/statements.

thank you.

Answer (score 2):

When trying at add breakpoints for a .jsp page it turned out the page was not opened with a JSP editor, which prevented the setting of breakpoints.

Answer (score 1):

> although I have attached a source directory to this .JAR file, I am unable to place a breakpoint in this class.

You say "a source directory". Are you sure, it's the same version that was used to compile the jar? If you're attaching a different source code version, the line numbers may not match, and your break point won't hit.

Comment: hi chris,

  yes, i compiled the jar myself from the sources. So, i know that the source directory and the .JAR are in sync.

  Otherwise, This .JAR was prepared from multiple projects. It source directory had the following structure

sourceDir
  A
    org
      fcitmuk
        db
  B
    org
      fcitmuk
         epihandy
  C
    org
      fcitmuk
         epihandy
           xform
  D
    org
      fcitmuk
        epihandy


Any clues ?

Answer (score 1):

I m aware of a bug in eclipse where break points dont work with a specific version of jdk 1.6.x
For more info look at [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=279137)

Comment: thank you. this was a problem in JDK 1.6.0_14 but was fixed in 1.6.0_16 . I am currently using 1.6.0_18 and I have this issue. Something tells me that I have forgotten something but can't place it! :-(

Answer (score 1):

Use a plugin called Jadclipse to decompile the jar in runtime, place the breakpoint at the point where the JAR method is invoked, then press F6 and you should be able to go into your JAR method.

Comment: I have the source for the .JAR so there is no need for doing JAD at run-time

Comment: Is the JAR compiled from the same source you have attached? This is crucial because otherwise line numbers don't match and it may not work when you attach the code.

Comment: When source and .JAR are not in sync, then eclipse's breakpoints act crazy and I've seen such a thing happening earlier. But this time, I cannot set a BP anywhere in the class, not even a single BP.

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple refresh of the .jar file did the trick for me.

I was able to place breakpoints in all the other class files of the same package except one. What I observed is that, when I opened this class file in editor and selected "Link with Editor", eclipse did not take me to this class file itself, but only to the package of this class file.

After the refresh,"Link with Editor" worked and I was able to place the breakpoint.

If someone could explain this behavior,it will be helpful.

Answer (score -3):

**Step1: Toggle/Enable breakpoint**
Set the breakpoint at the line of code or point of method entry from where you would like to start debugging the code. Right click on the left margin of the editor next to the line of code and a context menu pops up. Select toggle breakpoint in the context menu

**Step2: Configure the breakpoint to stop execution**
To start debugging, the execution should stop at the breakpoint specified. For this click on breakpoint properties and do the following:

```
1. Check Hit count
2. Specify value as 1
3. Select “Suspend thread” option
```

This will stop the execution when the program hits the breakpoint.

**Step3: Switch to debug perspective**

In Eclipse, select Window –>Open Perspective –> Debug

**Step4: Run in debug mode**

Now run the program in debug mode. Select Run –> Debug

Now the program starts running in debug mode and you would see the state of the thread as “running”

When the program hits the breakpoint the state of the thread changes from “running” to “suspended”

**Step5: Debugging the code with Expressions \Watch variables \ Inspect**

Now the code stops at the breakpoint. You could use the watch variables / expression to monitor the current value of the debug variable.
Suppose you set the breakpoint at the variable named “counter” and the program stopped at counter variable
Add the expression with the variable name “counter” which allows you to monitor the value of the variable as you execute the program
You could also right click on the counter variable and select “Inspect” from the context menu
If it is a method then, select the method name and click on “Step Into Selection“. This will allow you to monitor or debug the method execution line by line.

**Step6: Use F6 key to step into the method**

To “step into” the next executable line of code in the current method, press the “F6 Key”. This will pass the program control from the current line to the next executable line of code.

Comment: This comment doesn't answer a single question that the OP asked.