# Sometimes I can no longer set breakpoints in Eclipse, how can I solve it without reopening the file?

Tags: eclipse, breakpoints

Sometimes, during a debugging session, the ability to set breakpoints in Eclipse seems to break. From that moment onwards, double-clicking the margin no longer shows a blue ball, and neither does right clicking and explicitly asking to "toggle break point". This happens for all the lines.

- This happens rarely, but I already remember quite a few times it happened to me, on different machines, different operating systems and different Eclipse versions (3.6/3.7, maybe also 3.5)
- The file is saved and refreshed.
- This is a Java project in classic Eclipse.
- The line is a valid line for a breakpoint - in fact, once this happens, *no* line can get a breakpoint.
- Closing and re-opening the file, or restarting Eclipse, seems to solve the issue.

Because of the last bullet I'm pretty sure this is a bug of some sort. How can I avoid this behavior?

Comment: Is it because of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187805/eclipse-helios-ignores-breakpoints? Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415655/unable-to-place-breakpoints-in-eclipse (jar path issue), http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022007/why-are-my-breakpoints-ignored-with-gwt-eclipse-and-java-1-6-0-14 (jdk version issue)

Comment: If your file has, as an icon, an "hollow J", I have posted below a possible explanation.

Comment: @VonC thanks for the links... unfortunately, it appears none of these questions describe the same issue I am experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

As illustrated by [bug 125768](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=125768) and [bug 322625](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=322625), the already-defined breakpoints can disappear when the source file opened is not the one referenced by your project (internal file with an `IResource`), but an external one (like one created on the fly by a decompiler)
.

In that case, you see something similar to:

[image: no more breakpoint in the source]

> The file is the source for a compiled class that's in a JAR (i.e.
>   read-only, non-editable).
>
> It seems that the IDE doesn't always pick that up as a "Java file that's on the
>   classpath". Other editors have the "J" icon with the binary underlay.
>
> I just checked: If I get the hollow "J", then breakpoints aren't visible.

Comment: Thanks, but the file in question is a writable Java file from my own project, not from any external jar. The icon isn't a hollow J.

Comment: @Oak: very strange, then. I always know that bug when Eclipse decided to open the code from another source than the one used to set the breakpoint. I will follow this page, hoping you find the answer.